# How to prevent USB flash drive viruses

Tags: virus, usb

Can anyone tell me what is the safest way to use flash drive in a secured network( I am not looking for a way to block it). i need a safe practice to use flash drive in a windows network.

My Imaginations About This:

I was thinking to deploy a Linux based USB Server with updated antivirus, as entry point of flash drive into my windows network.
Benefits:

Linux doesn't understand exe file so virus will not be executed and spread all over the network.
Windows virus will be as a dead-body on Linux file system, so it can be easily removed by antivirus or manually.
Concern: - But still there is chance someone copy virus files by mistake to a windows machine to make it alive. So i need your advise on this topic if someone using any solution to prevent spreading viruses coming from usb drive.

Comment: I personally don't see the advantage of the "dead code" if you're going to execute code on the windows machine anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You would need your Linux server to have anti-virus that scans for Windows viruses. As far as I know, there aren't many such AV's. Furthermore, what's to stop someone from putting a Linux virus on the flash drive, instead? Your idea does raise the bar, mostly due to its obscurity, but I don't think you are getting enough for the effort and complexity of this solution.